# How to display Barcode Scanner in android

Tags: android

Hi guys iam developing an Android application which needs a Barcode Scanner to be launch when i click on a button .I have seen so many apps in the internet like Zxing.But i have seen that we need to install the project in our device and call an intent from our app to launch it.Here i dont want to use the installed app in my own app.Is it possible to develop a Bar Code Scanner through code so that it doesnt depends on the installed applications in the device.And at the same time i need to capture the Barcode and display in a Textview.Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the source code from the ZXing app instead of making your own scanner. Their source code is included on their downloads page at http://code.google.com/p/zxing/. It would definitely be more work than just relying on an intent to their application, but a lot less work than making a barcode scanner from scratch.